# XSLT mapping to remove double quotes only at starting and ending positions

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Experts, i need to write XSLT 1.0 code to eliminate the double quotes at starting and ending of the field ( in short, starting and ending position double quote only), not supposed to remove any other  double quote in the input field.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>"88245"322"2608""</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>"22219"</CreDtTm>
             <OrgnlNbOfTxs>12"3"41</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
        </GrpHdr>
       
    </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

** Desired Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>88245"322"2608"</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>22219</CreDtTm>
             <OrgnlNbOfTxs>12"3"41</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
        </GrpHdr>
       
    </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

** XSLT I used is below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '\&quot;', '')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT removing the all the double quotes from my input field, please assist here..

Comment: Well, https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with exists for the check, similarly you can check that `substring(., string-length(.)) = '"'` for the end, then use `substring` to remove the first and/or the last character if they are quotes. Or check whether you XSLT 1 processor has any regular expression support similar to the XPath 2 `replace(., '^"|"$', '')`.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/text()">
   
       <xsl:value-of select="substring(., string-length(.)) = '"' />
       
           
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: i tried above code, but giving some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of 
       select="concat(
                 translate(substring(., 1, 1), '&quot;', ''), 
                 substring(., 2, string-length() - 2), 
                 translate(substring(., string-length()), '&quot;', '')
               )"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could look at it:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="len" select="string-length()" />
    <xsl:variable name="s" select="starts-with(., '&quot;')" />
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="substring(., $len) = '&quot;'" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1 + $s, $len - $s - $e)" />
</xsl:template>
```

---

Of course, if you know that some elements will **always** have leading and trailing quotes, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:MsgId | ns0:CreDtTm">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2, string-length() - 2)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

provided you include:

```
xmlns:ns0="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0"
```

in the `xsl:stylesheet` start-tag.